# Angular 2 Material: sidenav focus on the first navigation item

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using [Angular 2 Material](https://material.angular.io/) and I have an issue with my navigation inside a sidenav component. Every time when I open the sidenav it automatically sets focus to the first `md-button` item and doesn't disappear until I click somewhere on the screen.

This is an example: https://plnkr.co/edit/pNv9Bx4o1qQSF2bpOqyM?p=preview

I tried to set `focus()` to another element on `sidenav.open()` event but a blinking effect appears for a second.

Is there any option or property that can disable this initial focus to the first menu item?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This has been resolved as of this github [issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10402)

You can just pass false to the autoFocus property:

```
<mat-sidenav [autoFocus]="false">
    ...
</mat-sidenav>
```

Comment: Works perfect for me, using @angular/cdk 7.1.1, @angular/cli  7.1.2, @angular/material 7.1.1.

Comment: Wow... Thanks a lot! worked with angular 9.x.x. and angular material 9.2.x

Comment: works in angular 11.x.x as well. Thanks

Comment: It is a concise solution and works in Angular 13.x.x as well. Thanks!

Comment: Can confirm, this works for Angular & Angular Material v17

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT** This has been resolved in the Material library, please see @Smiter's answer.

So, this does seem to be a bug with `md-sidenav` when `mode='side'`. There are a few issues open on GitHub (OP, I saw that you submitted your own as well; good work). Playing around with it, it seems that it's actually related to the `md-button` directive on the anchor tags. Replacing the `<a>` tags with `<button>`s also did not fix it as long as the `md-button` is still there. As further evidence, removing the `md-button` from the first `<a>` tag causes the *second* list item (the first element with an `md-button`) to highlight itself this way.

Anyway, I think the best way to fix this would be to shim in a workaround until we hear from the Angular team. I was able to fix the behavior by adding a invisible list item with a `md-button` first on the list:

```
  <md-sidenav #sidenav class="example-sidenav">

    <a md-button style="height: 0; position: absolute;"> <!-- 'absorbs' the behavior -->
    </a>  

    <md-list>

      <md-list-item>
        <a (click)="sidenav.close()" md-button>
          <md-icon>directions_car</md-icon>
        </a>
      </md-list-item>
      ......
    </md-list>
  </md-sidenav>
```

Note that we can't set `display: none` on the dummy element; the directive would ignore it. Just use `height: 0` or something similar. I also set `position: absolute` so it didn't mess with the positioning of the other elements.

EDIT: Here's the issue. According to one collaborator this is working as intended? Keep an eye out - if that is true, this needs to be submitted as a feature request, because it's confusing to the user.
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3215

Comment: Yeah, the no height solution fixes the issue. I thought that maybe I miss something but definitely, it's a bug. Thanks for the support and hope that very soon this bug will be fixed ;)

Comment: this is issue is resolved now, as the other answer states. Use that, this workaround is no longer required.

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute to the focused button:

`onclick="this.blur()"`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.